# Gluing a graph $G$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have a question about gluing a graph. Let us consider a graph $G$ as shown in the figure.

[image]

How would the graph obtained from $G$ by identifying the edge $b$ with the edge $b'$ and the vertex $x$ with $x'$ and $y$ with $y'$, look like?

Remark: This type of graphs is called snake graphs and in the text they say that this form of gluing is called band graph or ouroboros (a snake devouring its tail). I have tried to find a planar graph, simply by identifying the edges in the above mentioned way, but I can't find the resemblance to the name above. That's why I wanted to know how this gluing looks like, since in the text they don't show it, they only draw the graph with the identified edges (like the torus and the square, for example).

Comment: Please [provide additional context and show some effort](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Why are you interested in this? Did you try to draw it? What's troubling you?

Comment: Hello, yes. The context is that this type of graphs is called snake graphs and in the text they say that this form of gluing is called band graph or ouroboros (a snake devouring its tail).

Comment: I have tried to find a planar graph, simply by identifying the edges in the above mentioned way, but I can't find the resemblance to the name above.  That's why I wanted to know how this gluing looks like, since in the text they don't show it, they only draw the graph with the identified edges (like the torus and the square, for example).

Comment: The unglued graph looks like a snake already and considering $b$ at the mouth end and $b'$ at the tail, the description makes sense to me.

Comment: Yes, but I was left wondering how it would look, for example if we glued it like the torus. It seems to me that it would come out something like an ice cream cone.

Comment: Instead of commenting please include context, clarification and your own effort in the question itself by [editing](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4150839/edit) it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll label the other vertices in the snake graph as below.[image]

Since we identify $x$ with $x'$ and $y$ with $y'$, I replace the edges $\{v,x\}$ and $\{u,y\}$ with $\{v,x'\}$ and $\{u,y'\}$, which gives the following band graph. [image]

Something the authors of the original paper want you to note is that nonisomorphic snake graphs can give rise to isomorphic band graphs. The snake graph below is not isomorphic to the snake graph above. However, the band graph it produces is isomorphic to the band graph above, albeit with different labels. [image] [image]